# Как удалить с начала и конца строки заданный повторяющийся символ?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Необходимо преобразовать строки вида:

```
'------example-1--'
```

в

```
'example-1'
```

Т.е. удалить с начала и конца строки все символы '-' (прочерк).

Как это сделать лаконично в хранимой процедуре mySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хранимaя процедура тут не нужна, есть стандартная функция [TRIM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Пример (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f0056944b965108d05d4cfee22c7d0b4)):

```
select trim(both '-' from '------example-1--') result;

result
----------
example-1
```